# Getting total percentage split after group by in sql

Tags: sql

I have a 3 tables that have the same structure:

`table_1`

```
country     user_id
US          1
BR          2
CN          3
RU          4
```

`table_2`

```
country     user_id
US          5
BR          6
CN          7
RU          8
```

`table_3`

```
country     user_id
US          9
BR          10
CN          11
CN          12
```

I am trying to get the total percentage of users by country from all 3 tables. For one table I've used this:

```
select country, count(*) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from table_1) as percentage
from table_1
group by country
order by percentage desc;
```

And I get the result I desire:

```
US  20
BR  15
CN  13
LV  0.75
...
```

How can I get the percentage of countries from all 3 tables combined? I suppose no join is required here, just counting the total rows by country after grouping but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` and analytic function `SUM`, that exists for most of the databases. The inner `COUNT` counts rows per country, while outer `SUM` sums them up over the entire result set.

```
select
  country,
  count(1) * 100.0 / sum(count(1)) over() as percentage
from (
  select country
  from table_1

  union all

  select country
  from table_2

  union all

  select country
  from table_3
)
group by country
```

Or calculate total count as separate subquery, if your database does not support it.

```
select
  country,
  count(1) * 100.0
   / (
      (select count(1) from table_1)
      + (select count(1) from table_2)
      + (select count(1) from table_3)
   ) as percentage
from (
  select country
  from table_1

  union all

  select country
  from table_2

  union all

  select country
  from table_3
)
group by country
```

Comment: It looks like it returns the total sum of rows with that country, not a percentage.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis I'm sorry, edited. It should sum up counts of course

Comment: The second one returns an `int`, so for countries that have `<0` has a `0`, I would like to see `0.36`, is that possible?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Yes, just use 100 as explicit decimal literal (`100.0`). Some databases can handle this without such a hint. Updated my answer with this additional info. But analytical function is more flexible and easy to read way, I think.